# Virtual function doesnt work

Tags: c++-cli

Everytime I call Draw method it always called for base class...

```
   #pragma once
    #include <pch.h>

    class A
    {
    public:
        A();

        virtual void Draw(CanvasDrawingSession^ drawingSession);
    };
```

Class B derived from A

```
#pragma once
#include <pch.h>
#include <A.h>

class B: public A
{
public:
    B();

    void Draw(CanvasDrawingSession^ drawingSession);
};
```

When I initialize base class object with derived class object A a = B() and call Draw method - a.Draw() it will always call Draw() from base class. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `A a = B()` is doing *object slicing*, essentially converting your `B` instance into an `A` instance. Polymorphism in C++ works through *pointers* and *references* to base classes.

Answer (score 2):

The code
     A a = B() 
constructs an instance of type B, and then assigns it to a variable of type A.  The compiler has generated for you a default copy constructor ...

```
A::A(const A&)
```

... that works fine for assignment from a variable of type `B`, because any instance of `B` is an instance of type `A` (because it's a subclass of `A`).

This effect is known as [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

To make your code work, don't throw away the `B`-ness.   You could for example do this:

```
B the_b = B();
A* a_ptr = &the_b;
a_ptr->Draw()
```

That will call `B::Draw()`.

Comment: That is why my example initialized ```a_ptr``` with ````A* a_ptr = &the_b;````.